# Populate dropdown list with dictionary values using html helpers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html-helper

I create a dictionary and set it with enum values. I want to use Html.DropdownlistFor populating dropdown list. This is my action:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
     Dictionary<string, string> TagsDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
     Enum.GetNames(typeof(System.Tags)).ToList().ForEach(x => TagsDictionary.Add(x, Resources.PageResources.ResourceManager.GetString(String.Format("Tags_{0}", x))));           
     return View(TagsDictionary);
 }
```

But i don't know how to write View to get dictionary values in dropdownlist when page loaded

Comment: why do you want to create a dictionary for populating a dropdown in the view?

Answer (score 1):

Use `SelectListItem`:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<SelectListItem> tagsList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    Enum.GetNames(typeof(System.Tags)).ToList()
        .ForEach(x => tagsList .Add(new SelectListItem(){Value = x, Text = Resources.PageResources.ResourceManager.GetString(String.Format("Tags_{0}", x))}));
    return View(tagsList );
}
```

In your view you can just call:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Tags List", Model)
```

Comment: When your write `return View(yourVariableHere);` the Razor engine automatically sets the value of the `Model` variable inside your view to `yourVariableHere`. The view has no reference the variable in your controller but can access the value trough the `Model`.

Comment: No, there's no need to. Inside your view, the `Model`_is_ `tagsList`. You don't need anything more.

Comment: Use `Model`. It's really the same thing, just with another name.

Comment: @Html.DropDownList("Tags List", Model) cant convert my model to seleclist

Comment: Do you have a `@model` definition in your view?

Comment: If you have a `@model` definition that's not of type `List<SelectListItem>`, that might cause your error. If you use this model in other paces in your view (other than the drop-down) you can save the drop down in `VieBag`: in controller write `ViewBag.DropDown = tagsList; return View();` and in your view just call `@Html.DropDownList("Tags List", ViewBag.DropDown)`.

Comment: I used dictionary but the point is returning data with view model. Thank you

Comment: You can either create a `List<SelectListItem>` as @AndreiV suggested, or generate the list inside the view from your `Dictionary<>`, something like `List<SelectListItem> lst = new List<SelectListItem>();
    Model.ToList().ForEach(x => lst.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = x.Value, Value = x.Key }));`